# Forbidden Invalid CSRF Token +monit

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I have installed monit on AWS ec2 and it working fine. But when I try to restart the nginx service through monit UI,i got an error like "Forbidden Invalid CSRF Token +monit".

My configuration

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
```

Answer (score 4):

monit implement [double-submit cookie pattern](https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts/2016/11/msg00182.html) to protect from csrf attacks, it send a cookie called `securitytoken` with post requests, but up to (at least) version 1.20 didn't take into account the presence of other cookies before the one mentioned.

Beside upgrading to a newer version where [it should be fixed](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/535/invalid-csrf-token) there's a simple workaround, just delete the other cookies using the browser or make `securitytoken` the first in the list.

Comment: Of course, one simple way to get around the cookies problem is to use `incognito` mode or something similar.  That worked for me.